# Error while downloading %username%.txt from web server using vbscript

Tags: html, vbscript, pcloud

I have a file admin.txt on pcloud server and my pc user name is admin.so i tried to get file admin.txt with following vscript.

```
Dim myURL 
Dim password
Dim username 
Dim strUserName
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strUserName = wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERNAME%.txt")
WScript.Echo "User Name: " & strUserName
myURL = "https://webdav.pcloud.com/Public%20Folder/%USERNAME%.txt"
username = "xyz@gmail.com"
password = "xyz"

Dim HttpReq
Set HttpReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0")
HttpReq.Open "GET", myURL, False, username, password
HttpReq.Send
myURL = HttpReq.ResponseBody

If HttpReq.Status = 200 Then
    Set oStrm = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    oStrm.Open
    oStrm.Type = 1
    oStrm.Write HttpReq.ResponseBody
    oStrm.SaveToFile "D:/%USERNAME%.txt", 2 ' change your path here...
    oStrm.Close
End If
```

**ERROR MESSAGE:**

> line 16
>   char 1
>   Error: The parameter is incorrect.
>   code: 80070057
>   source: msxml3.dll

**NOTE:** 
On line

```
WScript.Echo "user name: " & strUserName
```

It shows my admin.txt name. But on line

```
myURL = "https://webdav.pcloud.com/public%20folder/%username%.txt"
```

It starts searching for `%username%.txt` to download instead of `admin.txt` which I want to download.

Comment: `myURL = "https://webdav.pcloud.com/Public%20Folder/%USERNAME%.txt" ` -> `myURL = wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("https://webdav.pcloud.com/Public%20Folder/%USERNAME%.txt")`

Comment: @Teemu Concatenation is not required. Environment variables are expanded even if the string contains other text.

Comment: @ Ansgar Wiechers  sir, here myURL = wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("https://webdav.pcloud.com/Public%20Folder/%USERNAME%.txt") ERROR: Object required: "

Comment: @user3275899 Please [edit] your question and show your updated code. It's clearly not possible that replacing the `myURL` assignment would raise that error when `strUserName = wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERNAME%.txt")` apparently worked just fine.

Comment: @ Ansgar Wiechers    Done. Thank you.

Comment: @user3275899 you haven't updated the code as Ansgar requested, please [edit] the question and show the updated code.

Comment: @Lankymart :  Code updated .

Comment: why down vote..!

Answer (score -1):

**Problem resolved ,code Working as expected .**

```
Dim myURL 
Dim password
Dim username 
Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strUserName = wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERNAME%.txt")
myURL = wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("https://webdav.pcloud.com/Public%20Folder/%USERNAME%.txt")
username = "xyz@gmail.com"
password = "xyz"
Dim HttpReq
Set HttpReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0")
HttpReq.Open "GET", myURL, False, username, password
HttpReq.Send
myURL = HttpReq.ResponseBody
If HttpReq.Status = 200 Then
    Set oStrm = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    oStrm.Open
    oStrm.Type = 1
    oStrm.Write HttpReq.ResponseBody
    oStrm.SaveToFile wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("D:/%USERNAME%.txt"), 2 
    oStrm.Close
End If
```